# Docusign Switch to New

Tags: docusignapi

The Docusign "Switch to New" from classic view is not taking any template changes that are made using the new view.
I have modified the template fields using the same account, still i am unable to see the changes reflected using the new view.
However if i use the classc view and am making any changes the template changes are visible.

Please suggest.

Comment: I believe that changes you make to a template in the new experience, may not be honored if you open/view the template in the classic experience. There are newer options/controls being added to the new experience, which can explain why it does not render when viewed in classic.

Comment: Both views should edit the same content functionally. On Demo I am able to create a template in Classic, modify tags in New, see changes in New and Classic. What environment are you using and can you share more of your workflow on what you're editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, The template changes done in the new experience is not reflecting at all. It is saying no permission, but I am able to modify the template using the classic view.

I think it works for simple templates but does not work in case there is heavy configuration done on the template using the docusign preferences menu where the signature and css are being modified.